# quick demo for dashboard ticking over

Tags: css, html, asp-classic

I have to mock up a ticking dashboard which is part of a proposal.  I am looking for ideas other than the HTTP Refresh option that I am thinking of.  The objective is to quickly mock up a look and feel and a working dashboard that ticks over.  It only had to provide new content every five seconds.  EG there are a bunch of KPI's and their outputs which are percentages have to be updated..

A simple bunch of HTML pages using HTTP Refresh is on my mind.  Is there a better option anyoine can think of. EG can HTML5 do this better?  Is CSS an option?  Thank you in advance for any ideas

Answer (score 0):

I would be going for an ajax call back to the server to get the latest update and then embed that wherever it needs to go - you could set the ajax function on a timer to run every 5 seconds or 1 second or whatever. This way your entire page is not being refreshed, and additionally you can be calling back to the server for a new update even while the previous on is still being rendered.

Downside is that you won't have a page history (i.e. the users will not be able to navigate 'back' to previous ajax updates) unless you explicitly create one; I can't see that being necessary though.

Please post a comment if you need more info about ajax.

Comment: HI @Katstevens thank you for your time.  I probably should have mentioned I am primarily a classic ASP guy.  To be honest I have never used ajax with classic ASP, have you?

Comment: I use ajax with asp.net, but came onto the 'asp scene' after .net 4, so I have no experience with classic asp. I'm not sure what they key points of difference are, but I know in ASP.NET you can use ScriptManager controls and ScriptProxy to control ajax panels that will execute the asynchronous update. Alternatively, jQuery has a nice ajax wrapper you can use, as long as you can get it to interface with whatever format your data is being provided on the server. Can you give some more specific info and I might be able to give a better answer?

Comment: I have done a bit of research and although I have never done so it looks like it can be used with classic ASP.  Becasue of time and cost on this task I have decided to go with using simple http refresh...fingers crossed the whole page refreshing wont be an issue.  So far it seems to be looking good.  Thank you for your time, have a good one!